# Why do I get a "the input data was invalid" error when I click "finish editing" in Experience Manager?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I edit a component on my homepage via Experience Manager and then click "Finish Editing".

The message bar at the top of my screen goes:

> Committing all changes...

And then:

> All changes have been committed

The preview pane then sits on "loading" for a while, before I get:

> The input data was invalid: 
>   Variant id of the request url must be equal to the one of the odata entity., 
>   Variant id of the request url must be equal to the one of the odata entity., 
>   Variant id of the request url must be equal to the one of the odata entity.

What is this error, and how do I fix it?

**Edit**

---

Not the original poster, but I've seen this issue in my environment as well, excerpt from my Preview logs below:

```
2013-09-18 07:34:10,259 DEBUG AbstractWritableEntryService - Inserting entity into webservice endpoint.

2013-09-18 07:34:10,260 DEBUG EntityParser - Parsing input string=

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"     xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">  
<category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="Tridion.ContentDelivery.CustomMeta" />  
<title />  
<author>    
  <name />  
</author>  
<updated>2013-09-18T12:34:09.4552367Z</updated>  
<id />  
<content type="application/xml">   
 <m:properties>      
 <d:DateValue m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />      
 <d:FloatValue m:type="Edm.Decimal">0</d:FloatValue>      
 <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:Id>      
 <d:ItemId m:type="Edm.Int32">9489</d:ItemId>      
 <d:ItemType m:type="Edm.Int32">64</d:ItemType>      
 <d:KeyName>nav_order</d:KeyName>      
 <d:PublicationId m:type="Edm.Int32">12</d:PublicationId>      
 <d:StringValue m:null="true" />    
 </m:properties>  
 </content>
 </entry> with mediaType=application/atom+xml.

2013-09-18 07:34:10,261 DEBUG ValidationUtils - Invoking validator [com.tridion.webservices.odata.validators.CustomMetaValidator@7b220575]

2013-09-18 07:34:10,261 DEBUG ValidationUtils - Validator found 1 errors

2013-09-18 07:34:10,261 ERROR ODataWebserviceHandler - Validation exception while updating an entity.
com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataValidationException: The input data was invalid: stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in., stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in., stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in.
at         com.tridion.webservices.odata.AbstractWritableEntryService.insert(AbstractWritableEntryService.java:53) ~[cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
at     com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.insertODataEntity(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:306) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
at     com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleChangeSet(ODataBatchHandler.java:113) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleBatch(ODataBatchHandler.java:52) [cd_webservice.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleBatch(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:346) [cd_webservice.jar:na]

2013-09-18 07:34:10,262 ERROR ODataBatchHandler - Operation failed with status code 400, rolling back the transaction and generating error response.

2013-09-18 07:34:10,262 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Rolling back storage transaction: 0154a9d3-74a1-40c2-96dd-90e5504ad88a

2013-09-18 07:34:10,262 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - rollback

2013-09-18 07:34:10,265 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit

2013-09-18 07:34:10,266 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - rolled back JDBC Connection

2013-09-18 07:34:10,266 DEBUG ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection

2013-09-18 07:34:10,266 DEBUG ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]

2013-09-18 07:34:10,266 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Nothing to roll back for transaction 0154a9d3-74a1-40c2-96dd-90e5504ad88a.

2013-09-18 07:34:10,266 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Cleaning up transaction 0154a9d3-74a1-40c2-96dd-90e5504ad88a.

2013-09-18 07:34:10,267 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Batch response: --batch_5a63d00c-baa1-46a3-9966-8ead0d2c36c7
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: multipart/mixed
Content-Length: 730

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code></code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">The input data was invalid: stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in., stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in., stringValue must be a non-empty string or any of the other values should be filled in.</message>
</error>
--batch_5a63d00c-baa1-46a3-9966-8ead0d2c36c7--

    2013-09-18 07:34:10,268 DEBUG ODataService - Adding header to response: X-Preview-Session-Token with value: zXaCM2HYXxDoNE7zClFwnChCPCVsS9bM/9NfQYCh0qtYRDHRbjdG8YcKBWhmCh+m
2013-09-18 07:34:10,268 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: Thread-7
2013-09-18 07:34:10,269 DEBUG HttpModule - Dispatching OnRequestEnd event
2013-09-18 07:34:10,269 DEBUG WebContext - setCurrentClaimStore: null, thread: Thread-11
```

Comment: What did you try? Check out all the logs (set loglevel to DEBUG or VERBOSE in logback.xml). If that doesn't give you a clue, post a follow-up.

Comment: That's a bit of a strange error. My guess is that it is due to an incorrect URL for the website (resulting in an incorrect query). Check the value of the "Content Delivery Endpoint URL" field on the "Session Preview" tab of the relevant Publication Target. If you don't immediately see something wrong with it, try opening it in a browser.

Comment: Did you checked the available HotFixes for Site Edit mentioned on the SDL Tridion World Site?

Comment: @George did you ever come to a solution or this is still an open issue, perhaps you can provide an update (with either more information or the solution)?

Comment: Are you sure this is SiteEdit and not Experience Manager?

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett, likely since the `Finish Editing` button wasn't available in SiteEdit.

Comment: @George I have re-tagged your question and edited to remove the references to SiteEdit. If this question was definitely about SiteEdit feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @GAG based on your log I'd check the content of your Components, I've seen issues before on 2011 where a mandatory field in the Component contained a null value (so `<field />` in the XML), this is not a valid value for the UI, but if it is in there, XPM/OData on 2011 had issues with that.

Comment: I have this issue with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1

Answer (score 2):

I guess by now this was fixed?

Anyway, it seems to be an error on the OData endpoint. The way to fix it is to set your ODATA webservice logs to DEBUG, try the operation, then look at the detail of the request coming in. Very likely, something is wrong with the ODATA configuration. If you can get more detail from the log, then post it here and someone might be able to help you.